# Using string.all with regex

Tags: android, kotlin

I am trying to check if a string has all the forbidden characters like "/#$%^&" ... 
i tried to find a solution but couldn't find anything , i just want to check if all characters in the string match regex pattern \w

string.all seems perfect but i cant add regex pattern to it
here is what i am trying to do:

```
 // "abce#ios" must return false because it contains #
 // "abcdefg123" must return true 

fun checkForChars(string :String) :Boolean {
    val pattern = "\\w".toRegex()
   return (string.contains(regex = pattern))
}
```

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You made several mistakes:

1. `\w` pattern matches exactly one letter, if you want to match zero or more letters you need to change it to: `\w*`
2. Instead of checking whether the string contains the regex, you need to check if it matches the regex.

The final solution is the following:

```
fun checkForChars(string :String) :Boolean {
    val pattern = "\\w*".toRegex()
   return (string.matches(pattern))
}
```

Comment: thanks for your help, that fixed the problem. but i didn't quite understand "\w*" pattern , i searched the web and found this "Matches the preceding element zero or more times." but still didn't understand, if u can explain i would be really grateful

Comment: "\w" if my string is 1 letter only?

Comment: `\w` matches 1 letter exactly, it will match only strings like "a", "b". Since your string can have zero or more letters you use the `*`. If you want to make sure that you have at least one letter then instead of `*` you put `+`

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to use regex at all with `all`:

```
fun checkForChars(string: String): Boolean = string.all(Char::isLetterOrDigit)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use
`Regex("[^/#$%^&]*").matches(string)` to check for the forbidden characters.

You can include any forbidden characters into a `[^...]*` construction. Though a `"` character would need to be screened and a `\` character would need to be screened twice. `Regex("[^\\\\/#$%^&\"]*")`.

For `\\w*` regex you can use `Regex("\\w*").matches(string)`